# cant press some of the keyboards buttons at the same time

Tags: keyboard

my new Logitech keyboard has worked for the entire summer but now, suddenly some of my buttons don't work when I try to press them while already pressing other buttons

edit:i cant seem to press shift a few non-numpad numbers, alt and spacebar while holding w. dont rember the model but i am on windows 10

and it might be the case becouse i was playing a game when it changed

I found the solution:my enter key was stuck idk how this affected the other side of the keyboard but well it works. the answer also helped as I started looking around my keyboard for some sortof button that did something and noticed my enter was stuck. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that you're experiencing the effects of a keyboard with poor *rollover* capability, meaning only a few keys can be registered simultaneously. However, considering this appears to be an unexpected change in circumstance, are you sure you haven't activated a mode on your keyboard designed specifically for preventing certain key combinations? For example, on some gaming keyboards, there is a key which disables the Windows/host key and thus its combinations.

Please try rewriting your question to include more details, such as the model of the keyboard and Windows version.

Comment: "_n-key rollover_" as a phrase is typically a _feature_ of high-end keyboards... look at [jamming / ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)). It would be better to just introduce the topic as "_rollover_"

Comment: Fair point, edited.